# How can I use wildcards in AWS S3 CLI, so that only files in the current directory are considered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

So, let's say I have the following AWS CLI command:

```
aws s3 cp --dryrun --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.log" --exclude "*/*" . s3://my-byucket/folder/
```

This will first exclude all files, include all .log files, and then exclude all files that are in a subdirectory (the order matters, the documentation says). It does what I want (get all .log files from my current directory only), but it has a serious downside: it will still look for these files in the subdirectories. Removing the '--recursive' flag will make the include/exclude functionality disappear, so that is not an option. However, recursing into all subdirectories could be an expensive operation, and is totally unnecessary in this case.

Is there an efficient way to solve this use case?